# Connected Vehicleシミュレータで車両が表示されない

Tags: bluemix

Geospatial Analytics を利用して、ネットワーク接続された車両の IoT アプリを作成する
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/mobile/library/mo-connectedcar-app/

このNode.jsのConnected Vehicleシミュレータが正しく動かせません。
cfコマンドラインからBluemixへのプッシュはエラーもなく完了するのですが、ブラウザでアプリを開くと地図上に車両が表示されません。
ブラウザはFirefox、Google Chrome、Internet Explorerいずれで試しても同じ状態です。
cfコマンドラインツールを最新バージョンにしても結果は変わりませんでした。

Connected Car Starter Kit
http://m2m.demos.ibm.com/trafficsimulator.html

検索してこの解説も見つけましたが問題判別に繋がる情報は見つけられませんでした。

なにか手順が抜けているのでしょうか。
うまく動いている方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

地図が表示されるということは、Bluemixへのデプロイは問題なく行えているようです。

現在はIoT FoundationのUIが変更されているので、developerWorksの記事とはデバイス追加の手順が異なりますが、設定が必要な項目はデバイスタイプとデバイスIDの二つだけです。もし他に設定したものがありましたら念のため外してみてください。

また、修正が必要なファイルは `manifest.yml` と `setting.js` の二つだけです。他のファイルは変更せずにそのままデプロイされていますでしょうか。
デプロイ自体は成功しているので `manifest.yml` は正しいものと思います。もしよろしければ `setting.js` を拝見できますか？
ただし、ここに引用していただく際に、**APIキー と 認証トークン は公開されないようご注意ください。**　xxxxx などで値をマスクしてください。